# I want QWebEngineView to behave like chrome

Tags: qt, google-chrome, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage, qwebengine

I am using a program called potreeConverter to convert a point cloud into an html page. If I see this page in chrome it looks great, however when i see it on firefox or in my QWebEngine View it looks bad. This is what is see on firefox and my QWebEngine:

[image: point cloud bad]

I want to see the same as in chrome in my QWebEngine. I tried to change the user agent, but nothing has changed.

The code:

```
QWebEngineProfile *profile = webEngineView_->page()->profile();
profile->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
profile->setHttpUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
```

What can i do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since it's clear that the problem is not directly related to QtWebEngine but also affects other browsers, you should contact the developers of that potreeConverter and ask them about it.

Comment: ok, i will do it, thanks

Comment: I tried in chromium and it looks good,  Why if qwebengine is based on chromium, the file doesn't looks good?